# Bootstrap css combination

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm designing new template with Bootstrap newest version.
I add new css (create style.css), it works offline. But when i upload it on hosting, it cannot load. This is my code:

```css
.custom_banner
{
 position: relative;
 float: left;
 margin-left: 1%;
 min-height: 150px;
 width: 24%;
 background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% #0080ff;
 font-size:16px;
 font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
}
.custom_banner:hover
{
 transition:all 0.45s ease 0s;
 background-color: #17577e;
}
.custom_banner p{
 padding: 22px 30px 20px;
 color: white;
}
.custom_banner span{
 font-size:50px;
 color: white;
}
```

```html
 <a href=""><div class="custom_banner"><p align="center"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone"></span><br><br>ĐIỆN THOẠI DI ĐỘNG</p></div></a>
 <a href=""><div class="custom_banner"><p align="center"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-headphones"></span><br><br>TAI NGHE</p></div></a>
 <a href=""><div class="custom_banner"><p align="center"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span><br><br>DỊCH VỤ</p></div></a>
 <a href=""><div class="custom_banner"><p align="center"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-flash"></span><br><br>SẠC CÁP CASE</p></div></a>
```

It cannot load my div size and color. I see inside resource code, it combined all css to this. But not updated to the newest.

```
<link href="css/A.bootstrap.min.css+style.css+carousel.css,Mcc.w7RlcrlD_f.css.pagespeed.cf.D5toTaBknS.css" rel=stylesheet>
```

My link: http://kainvn.asia/template
Thanks for helps.

Comment: Did you create that link href, or was it auto generated?

Comment: @Anuj i created it.
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="css/carousel.css" rel="stylesheet">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run the page locally, it calls for the CSS locally **in your** hard drive. When you go to host it, the HTML can't call the CSS because it cannot find that local file anymore.

Try uploading the CSS into where you host you files (via FTP or website) and change the CSS link to call for it in the specific directory.

---

Example:

If you put the CSS file in the same directory as your CSS the link would look like:

```
<link href="myStylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

If you keep your stylesheets in a separate folder (within the one the HTML is in) than you would need to add it to the file path. Lets say you keep your stylesheets in a folder  named "css", then the link would look something like this:

```
<link href="css/myStylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Hope this helped!

Comment: I still keep it on same hosting, and i called link:  
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
But problem is, it joined into 1 link 
<link href="css/A.bootstrap.min.css+style.css+carousel.css,Mcc.w7RlcrlD_f.css.pagespeed.cf.D5toTaBknS.css" rel=stylesheet>
We can see it attached "style.css", but still got errors i dont know.
Can you look more deep inside code? This is my html: http://pastebin.com/8qNqk0Lr
Thanks

Comment: Split up the combined link into multiple links, then try it again.

Comment: It combined automatically, my "real code" are multiple links